# How to expand iOS Today Widget by default?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-extensions

I'm setting `[self.extensionContext setWidgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode:NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded]` in `viewDidLoad` and, as expected, I'm getting the "show more" button that toggles between compact and expanded widget mode.
When the widget starts, it's always in compact mode by default. How can I change that and make widget be in expanded mode when it starts?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, seems like it would be really annoying if every widget could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible.

A widget should not take over the screen by default. It defeats the purpose of a widget. You should make the content you want to display to user minimum and small (like a brief info), and user should be able to expand to view more details. This is how Widget works as intended.